# Is it possible to run two apks simultaneously and make them communicate through a windows service?

Tags: service, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin.forms to create an equivalent of a windows forms app in mobile, the windows app runs two exe files at the same time and the exe files communicate with each other through a windows service, I want to know if the same thing is possible in xamarin.forms, I mean if it is possible to publish two apks under one app and how? and if so, how to communicate between the two apks? Is it possible to use the same windows service that we're using in our windows app?

**EDIT**

What I want to achieve by communicating is the exact same thing we have in windows, we're trying to use the same code we have used in our windows app, as much as possible, as I explained in my question, we're using a sevice to comminucate between two exe files, I know it's not possible to run an `exe` in `Android OS`, but I thought if I could use the code of the `exe` files in `xamarin` and create a UI for them and turn them to `apk` (but not seperate `apks`, if possible) and communicate between these two, then we will be able to achive the same functionality we have in Windows.Forms. I don't want to open another app in my main app, I just want to use the data of the second app in my main app.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean if it is possible to publish two apks under one app and how?

No, it is **not possible** to publish two apks under one app. An app only contains an apk, both `iOS` and `Android` will not allow you to do that.

> Is it possible to use the same windows service that we're using in
>   our windows app?

No, windows service is not available on iOS and Android. They(iOS and Android) are independent mobile operating system developed by `Apple` and `Google`. Windows has nothing to do with iOS and Android.

Comment: Thank you, so is there any other way to communicate between two apps? Besides, what's this link about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552706/communication-between-2-apps-on-same-device-ios-android-with-xamarin  I want the same functionality, somethig like an add-on app that has been mentioned in this link

Comment: @ReihanehKhaksaran Yes, you can `communicate` between two different apps.  For example, you can share something from `facebook` to `whatsapp`, you can also open app A when you are using app B, sharing some documents, open some files with another app and so on, I think these are called `communication` between apps. I think the link you mentioned is about linking to other Apps, like open app A in app B, or like `deep link`, open an app through a url(This always appears in your `SMS` message, a `url` in the message, once you touch it, you will jump to specify app automatically).

Comment: And you want know what is `Microservices`? What would you like to achieve by  communicating between two apps?

Comment: No, I don't want the communication to be through URL, I want them to communicate with 'services' (no UI), don't know if that's something that can be achieved with `Microservice` or `WCF`.

Comment: and I edited my question to explain more about what I want to achieve by communicating between two apps

Comment: I don't want to open another app in my main app, I just want to use the data of the second app in my main app.

Comment: @ReihanehKhaksaran I have't tried to communicate two apps with `services` so far.  Apps always communicate with the server side(back end). You can send data from A--> server side -->B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185971/discussion-between-jack-hua-msft-and-reihaneh-khaksaran).